# automatically choose viewResolver based on request url?

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller, jackson

What I'd like to be able to do is write one method that will return an object, map the method to a request, and alter how the object is formatted based on the url.  So, if I had an array of Client objects that get returned for `/clients`, I'd like to, by default, resolve the object to a velocity template (clients.vm) to handle the formatting.  However, if the url is `/clients.json`, than I'd like to pass the object back in the response body, and let the message converter figure out how to handle it.

So, my question is, how do I configure Spring, and how do I write the controller?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use a `PathVariable` in your handler method, use that to toggle which view to use:

```
@RequestMapping("/myapp/{viewtype}/view.do")
public String myHandler(
      @PathVariable String viewtype,
      Model model) {
  // do stuff
  return "viewname." + viewtype;
}
```

View type could be `vm`, or `jsp`, or whatever.  It could also return JSON if the return type is simply changed to `@ResponseBody` and you have the Jackson JARs on the classpath.