# Spring MVC: Ensure parameter is valid, cross cutting through many controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-aop

I have a restful server using spring mvc.  Many of the controllers (though not all) take a certain path parameter /fruits/{type}.

I need to centrally configure what types of fruit are acceptable.  I.e., apple, banana, cherry are ok.  For everything else I need to throw a 400 level http status code.

It is important that this be done quickly and elegantly.  Some ways that this can be done are:

1. I write some kind of utility pojo and invoke it's method in every controller method that handles /fruit/{type}.  Seems pretty cludgy.
2. A spring web request interceptor
3. Spring security?
4. AOP?
5. Something else?

What is the most professional, quick, elegant way to achieve this goal?

Comment: why not manually check in your controller function?? Just make a list of accepted/rejected fruits in an array then you just need to check if fruits is accepted/rejected...

Comment: Because there are lots of controller methods (but not all of them) that all need to do the same thing.

Comment: did you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198486/spring-3-0-url-pattern-validation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989454/best-practice-for-validating-a-url-with-spring-mvc

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-validate-url-in-java/

Comment: Yes, but my question is - what is the best way to do this?  As opposed to, what are some ways to do this?  I am currently leaning towards an interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not get a 'best way' answer.  Each 'best way' depends on your specific situation, needs, and desires.  Here is 'a' way...

We do this via PropertyEditors during request Binding.

You could have one PropertyEditor per controller type and if you do not receive the correct type of 'thing' you're expecting then throw an exception from the PropertyEditor.

You can register your PropertyEditors per Controller or globally via a customized PropertyEditorRegistrar mapped to a RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

I would then use the Spring SimpleMappingExceptionResolver to map your different exceptions to the view and error code you want to return.

BTW, I would consider using 404 vs 400, but that is just me.